# Angular Service becomes undefined when spyOn it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, spyon

I have an Angular 1.6.6 application which I'm testing with Karma and Jasmine.

Given this code from controller:

```
    $scope.undo = function () {
        return $scope.isUndoDisabled() || $scope.undoAction();
    };

    $scope.isUndoDisabled = function () {
        return HistoryService.isUndoDisabled();
    };
```

I have been testing it with the following spec:

```
it('undoAction should not be called with default settings', function () {
        var $scope = {};
        var controller = $controller('PaintController', { $scope: $scope });

        spyOn($scope, 'undoAction');
        //spyOn(HistoryService, 'isUndoDisabled');

        $scope.undo();
        expect($scope.undoAction).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

And is **passing** the test, but when I uncomment the spyOn of HistoryService, the call `HistoryService.isUndoDisabled()` from `$scope.isUndoDisabled` returns undefined and then the test **fails** because:

> Expected spy undoAction not to have been called.

Any idea about what's going on???? It seems like the `spyOn` is affecting to the code??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spyOn(...)` is a shortcut for `spyOn(...).and.stub()`, not `spyOn(...).and.callThrough()`. When being spied this way, `HistoryService.isUndoDisabled()` returns `undefined`.

The proper way to test the unit is to isolate it from others. Since it is the controller that is tested, the service should be mocked or stubbed:

```
spyOn(HistoryService, 'isUndoDisabled').and.returnValue(true);
```

And then in another test:

```
spyOn(HistoryService, 'isUndoDisabled').and.returnValue(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to call isUndoDisabled() from HistoryService, the function $scope.isUndoDisabled should be

```
 $scope.isUndoDisabled = function () {
    HistoryService.isUndoDisabled();
};
```

There shouldn't be a return in the body